# getJSON to fetch data from this json array

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, getjson

This is a sample json array from my code. How can i use getJSON to fetch data from this array.

```
"Restoration": [
                {
                "Easy": {
                "value": "1",
                "info": "This is Easy."
                },
                "Medium": {
                "value": ".75",
                "info": "This is Medium."
                },
                "Difficult": {
                "value": ".5",
                "info": "This is Difficult."
                }
                }
                ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jQuery [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
 $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
     console.log(data); //see your data ( works in Chrome / FF with firebug)
     console.log(data["Restoration"][0]["easy"]["value"]) //should output 1
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to use **"jQuery.getJSON()"** because sometimes we don't have a "domain/file.json" or somewhere to do the $get or we don't want to use jQuery
for this simple process.

**This method parses json from string**.

You can do it with simple javascript like this:

```
//json string for testing
var jsonstr = '{"id":"743222825", "name":"Oscar Jara"}';

//parse json
var data = JSON.parse(jsonstr);

//print in console
console.log("My name is: " + data.name + " and my id is: " + data.id);
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: You didn't try to run the code yourself, did you? `JSON.parse` throws an error because the value you pass is not a string.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you were right, I missed the `quotes`, thanks for pointing this out (I've updated the post).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize this question was from 2012. Sorry, I would have just edited the answer myself instead of leaving an half-snarky comment :-/

Comment: @FelixKling No problem, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

http://underscorejs.org/#keys

```
var list=_.Keys(data["Restoration"][0]);
```