# How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, data-manipulation

I have a nested data structure containing objects and arrays. How can I extract the information, i.e. access a specific or multiple values (or keys)?

For example:

```
var data = {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
};
```

How could I access the `name` of the second item in `items`?

Comment: @Marcel: It has to be read as "I have a data nested data structure *or* JSON, how can I access a specific value?". *I* know the difference, but many people don't and might be searching for "JSON" rather than "object". Many questions actually are of the form "how can I access X in this JSON". The only place where I mention JSON in my answer is where I explain what it is. If you have a suggestion how to communicate this in a better way, I'm all ears.

Comment: There are so many way to access specific name in array of objects in object. for this scenario you can access it using "data.items[1].name" and for any custom name and other item you can use it this way "data.items[i][nameofvariable] . here i is position in array and nameofvariable is key which you want to access. for more detail about accessing you can check this link https://thecodingcloud.com/how-do-you-access-nested-objects-arrays-or-json-in-javascript/

Comment: Another handy and tiny library, SelectQL.js is inspired by Structured Query Language (SQL) for accessing and manipulating Objects in an easy and familiar way. It supports complex Objects and Arrays using Builder Design Pattern. https://www.npmjs.com/package/selectql.js

Answer (score 1467, accepted):

### Preliminaries

JavaScript has only one data type which can contain multiple values: **Object**. An **Array** is a special form of object.

(Plain) Objects have the form

```
{key: value, key: value, ...}
```

Arrays have the form

```
[value, value, ...]
```

Both arrays and objects expose a `key -> value` structure. Keys in an array must be numeric, whereas any string can be used as key in objects. The key-value pairs are also called the **"properties"**.

Properties can be accessed either using **dot notation**

```
const value = obj.someProperty;
```

or **bracket notation**, if the property name would not be a valid JavaScript [identifier name *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6), or the name is the value of a variable:

```
// the space is not a valid character in identifier names
const value = obj["some Property"];

// property name as variable
const name = "some Property";
const value = obj[name];
```

For that reason, array elements can only be accessed using bracket notation:

```
const value = arr[5]; // arr.5 would be a syntax error

// property name / index as variable
const x = 5;
const value = arr[x];
```

#### Wait... what about JSON?

JSON is a textual representation of data, just like XML, YAML, CSV, and others. To work with such data, it first has to be converted to JavaScript data types, i.e. arrays and objects (and how to work with those was just explained). How to parse JSON is explained in the question [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript) .

#### Further reading material

How to access arrays and objects is fundamental JavaScript knowledge and therefore it is advisable to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide), especially the sections

- [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object)
- [Eloquent JavaScript - Data Structures](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html)

---

---

### Accessing nested data structures

A nested data structure is an array or object which refers to other arrays or objects, i.e. its values are arrays or objects. Such structures can be accessed by consecutively applying dot or bracket notation.

Here is an example:

```
const data = {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
};
```

Let's assume we want to access the `name` of the second item.

Here is how we can do it step-by-step:

As we can see `data` is an object, hence we can access its properties using dot notation. The `items` property is accessed as follows:

```
data.items
```

The value is an array, to access its second element, we have to use bracket notation:

```
data.items[1]
```

This value is an object and we use dot notation again to access the `name` property. So we eventually get:

```
const item_name = data.items[1].name;
```

Alternatively, we could have used bracket notation for any of the properties, especially if the name contained characters that would have made it invalid for dot notation usage:

```
const item_name = data['items'][1]['name'];
```

---

#### I'm trying to access a property but I get only `undefined` back?

Most of the time when you are getting `undefined`, the object/array simply doesn't have a property with that name.

```
const foo = {bar: {baz: 42}};
console.log(foo.baz); // undefined
```

Use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) or [`console.dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir) and inspect the structure of object / array. The property you are trying to access might be actually defined on a nested object / array.

```
console.log(foo.bar.baz); // 42
```

---

#### What if the property names are dynamic and I don't know them beforehand?

If the property names are unknown or we want to access all properties of an object / elements of an array, we can use the [`for...in` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop for objects and the [`for` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop for arrays to iterate over all properties / elements.

**Objects**

To iterate over all properties of `data`, we can iterate over the **object** like so:

```
for (const prop in data) {
    // `prop` contains the name of each property, i.e. `'code'` or `'items'`
    // consequently, `data[prop]` refers to the value of each property, i.e.
    // either `42` or the array
}
```

Depending on where the object comes from (and what you want to do), you might have to test in each iteration whether the property is really a property of the object, or it is an inherited property. You can do this with [`Object#hasOwnProperty` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

As alternative to `for...in` with `hasOwnProperty`, you can use [`Object.keys` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an *array of property names*:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(prop) {
  // `prop` is the property name
  // `data[prop]` is the property value
});
```

**Arrays**

To iterate over all elements of the `data.items` **array**, we use a `for` loop:

```
for(let i = 0, l = data.items.length; i < l; i++) {
    // `i` will take on the values `0`, `1`, `2`,..., i.e. in each iteration
    // we can access the next element in the array with `data.items[i]`, example:
    // 
    // var obj = data.items[i];
    // 
    // Since each element is an object (in our example),
    // we can now access the objects properties with `obj.id` and `obj.name`. 
    // We could also use `data.items[i].id`.
}
```

One could also use `for...in` to iterate over arrays, but there are reasons why this should be avoided: [Why is 'for(var item in list)' with arrays considered bad practice in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265167/why-is-forvar-item-in-list-with-arrays-considered-bad-practice-in-javascript).

With the increasing browser support of ECMAScript 5, the array method [`forEach` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) becomes an interesting alternative as well:

```
data.items.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
    // The callback is executed for each element in the array.
    // `value` is the element itself (equivalent to `array[index]`)
    // `index` will be the index of the element in the array
    // `array` is a reference to the array itself (i.e. `data.items` in this case)
});
```

In environments supporting ES2015 (ES6), you can also use the [*`for...of`* *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, which not only works for arrays, but for any [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterable):

```
for (const item of data.items) {
   // `item` is the array element, **not** the index
}
```

In each iteration, `for...of` directly gives us the next element of the iterable, there is no "index" to access or use.

---

#### What if the "depth" of the data structure is unknown to me?

In addition to unknown keys, the "depth" of the data structure (i.e. how many nested objects) it has, might be unknown as well. How to access deeply nested properties usually depends on the exact data structure.

But if the data structure contains repeating patterns, e.g. the representation of a binary tree, the solution typically includes to [**recursively** *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) access each level of the data structure.

Here is an example to get the first leaf node of a binary tree:

```
function getLeaf(node) {
    if (node.leftChild) {
        return getLeaf(node.leftChild); // <- recursive call
    }
    else if (node.rightChild) {
        return getLeaf(node.rightChild); // <- recursive call
    }
    else { // node must be a leaf node
        return node;
    }
}

const first_leaf = getLeaf(root);
```

```js
const root = {
    leftChild: {
        leftChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 42
        },
        rightChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 5
        }
    },
    rightChild: {
        leftChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 6
        },
        rightChild: {
            leftChild: null,
            rightChild: null,
            data: 7
        }
    }
};
function getLeaf(node) {
    if (node.leftChild) {
        return getLeaf(node.leftChild);
    } else if (node.rightChild) {
        return getLeaf(node.rightChild);
    } else { // node must be a leaf node
        return node;
    }
}

console.log(getLeaf(root).data);
```

A more generic way to access a nested data structure with unknown keys and depth is to test the type of the value and act accordingly.

Here is an example which adds all primitive values inside a nested data structure into an array (assuming it does not contain any functions). If we encounter an object (or array) we simply call `toArray` again on that value (recursive call).

```
function toArray(obj) {
    const result = [];
    for (const prop in obj) {
        const value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            result.push(toArray(value)); // <- recursive call
        }
        else {
            result.push(value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```js
const data = {
  code: 42,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  }]
};


function toArray(obj) {
  const result = [];
  for (const prop in obj) {
    const value = obj[prop];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      result.push(toArray(value));
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(toArray(data));
```

---

---

### Helpers

Since the structure of a complex object or array is not necessarily obvious, we can inspect the value at each step to decide how to move further. [`console.log` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) and [`console.dir` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir) help us doing this. For example (output of the Chrome console):

```
> console.log(data.items)
 [ Object, Object ]
```

Here we see that that `data.items` is an array with two elements which are both objects. In Chrome console the objects can even be expanded and inspected immediately.

```
> console.log(data.items[1])
  Object
     id: 2
     name: "bar"
     __proto__: Object
```

This tells us that `data.items[1]` is an object, and after expanding it we see that it has three properties, `id`, `name` and `__proto__`. The latter is an internal property used for the prototype chain of the object. The prototype chain and inheritance is out of scope for this answer, though.

Comment: For those who are getting the data as undefine that can be solved by Optional Chaining. You can read more about this in this blog.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-the-question-mark-works-in-javascript/

Comment: _“JavaScript has only one data type which can contain multiple values: **Object**.”_ — We shouldn’t forget to update this as soon as the [Records & Tuples proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple) reaches stage 4 (maybe even stage 3?).

Answer (score 109):

You can access it this way

```
data.items[1].name
```

or

```
data["items"][1]["name"]
```

Both ways are equal.

Answer (score 51):

Objects and arrays has a lot of built-in methods that can help you with processing data.

Note: in many of the examples I'm using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are similar to [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), but they bind the `this` value lexically.

### [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) (ES 2017) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (ES 2017)

`Object.keys()` returns an array of object's keys, `Object.values()` returns an array of object's values, and `Object.entries()` returns an array of object's keys and corresponding values in a format `[key, value]`.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1
 ,b: 2
 ,c: 3
}

console.log(Object.keys(obj)) // ['a', 'b', 'c']
console.log(Object.values(obj)) // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(Object.entries(obj)) // [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
```

#### `Object.entries()` with a for-of loop and destructuring assignment

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1
 ,b: 2
 ,c: 3
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${value}`)
}
```

It's very convenient to iterate the result of `Object.entries()` with a [for-of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

For-of loop lets you iterate array elements. The syntax is `for (const element of array)` (we can replace `const` with `var` or `let`, but it's better to use `const` if we don't intend to modify `element`).

Destructuring assignment lets you extract values from an array or an object and assign them to variables. In this case `const [key, value]` means that instead of assigning the `[key, value]` array to `element`, we assign the first element of that array to `key` and the second element to `value`. It is equivalent to this:

```
for (const element of Object.entries(obj)) {
  const key = element[0]
       ,value = element[1]
}
```

As you can see, destructuring makes this a lot simpler.

### [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

The `every()` method returns `true` if the specified callback function returns `true` for *every* element of the array. The `some()` method returns `true` if the specified callback function returns `true` for *some* (at least one) element.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

// true, because every element is greater than 0
console.log(arr.every(x => x > 0))
// false, because 3^2 is greater than 5
console.log(arr.every(x => Math.pow(x, 2) < 5))
// true, because 2 is even (the remainder from dividing by 2 is 0)
console.log(arr.some(x => x % 2 === 0))
// false, because none of the elements is equal to 5
console.log(arr.some(x => x === 5))
```

### [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The `find()` methods returns *the first* element which satisfies the provided callback function. The `filter()` method returns an array of *all* elements which satisfies the provided callback function.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

// 2, because 2^2 !== 2
console.log(arr.find(x => x !== Math.pow(x, 2)))
// 1, because it's the first element
console.log(arr.find(x => true))
// undefined, because none of the elements equals 7
console.log(arr.find(x => x === 7))

// [2, 3], because these elements are greater than 1
console.log(arr.filter(x => x > 1))
// [1, 2, 3], because the function returns true for all elements
console.log(arr.filter(x => true))
// [], because none of the elements equals neither 6 nor 7
console.log(arr.filter(x => x === 6 || x === 7))
```

### [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The `map()` method returns an array with the results of calling a provided callback function on the array elements.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

console.log(arr.map(x => x + 1)) // [2, 3, 4]
console.log(arr.map(x => String.fromCharCode(96 + x))) // ['a', 'b', 'c']
console.log(arr.map(x => x)) // [1, 2, 3] (no-op)
console.log(arr.map(x => Math.pow(x, 2))) // [1, 4, 9]
console.log(arr.map(String)) // ['1', '2', '3']
```

### [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

The `reduce()` method reduces an array to a single value by calling the provided callback function with two elements.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

// Sum of array elements.
console.log(arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b)) // 6
// The largest number in the array.
console.log(arr.reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b)) // 3
```

The `reduce()` method takes an optional second parameter, which is the initial value. This is useful when the array on which you call `reduce()` can has zero or one elements. For example, if we wanted to create a function `sum()` which takes an array as an argument and returns the sum of all elements, we could write it like that:

```js
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

console.log(sum([]))     // 0
console.log(sum([4]))    // 4
console.log(sum([2, 5])) // 7
```

Comment: This is my favourite answer. You also could add an example for loop just an expecific nested data, like `Object.keys(data["items"]).forEach(function(key) {
      console.log(data["items"][key].id);
      console.log(data["items"][key].name);
 });`

Answer (score 39):

In case you're trying to access an `item` from the example structure by `id` or `name`, without knowing it's position in the array, the easiest way to do it would be to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library:

```
var data = {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
};

_.find(data.items, function(item) {
  return item.id === 2;
});
// Object {id: 2, name: "bar"}
```

From my experience, using higher order functions instead of `for` or `for..in` loops results in code that is easier to reason about, and hence more maintainable.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 31):

At times, accessing a nested object using a string can be desirable. The simple approach is the first level, for example

```
var obj = { hello: "world" };
var key = "hello";
alert(obj[key]);//world
```

But this is often not the case with complex json. As json becomes more complex, the approaches for finding values inside of the json also become complex. A recursive approach for navigating the json is best, and how that recursion is leveraged will depend on the type of data being searched for. If there are conditional statements involved, a [json search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11657379/1026459) can be a good tool to use.

If the property being accessed is already known, but the path is complex, for example in this object

```
var obj = {
 arr: [
    { id: 1, name: "larry" },    
    { id: 2, name: "curly" },
    { id: 3, name: "moe" }
 ]
};
```

And you know you want to get the first result of the array in the object, perhaps you would like to use

```
var moe = obj["arr[0].name"];
```

However, that will cause an exception as there is no property of object with that name. The solution to be able to use this would be to flatten the tree aspect of the object. This can be done recursively.

```
function flatten(obj){
 var root = {};
 (function tree(obj, index){
   var suffix = toString.call(obj) == "[object Array]" ? "]" : "";
   for(var key in obj){
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key))continue;
    root[index+key+suffix] = obj[key];
    if( toString.call(obj[key]) == "[object Array]" )tree(obj[key],index+key+suffix+"[");
    if( toString.call(obj[key]) == "[object Object]" )tree(obj[key],index+key+suffix+".");   
   }
 })(obj,"");
 return root;
}
```

Now, the complex object can be flattened

```
var obj = previous definition;
var flat = flatten(obj);
var moe = flat["arr[0].name"];//moe
```

Here is a ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/73172hr0/)*** of this approach being used.

Answer (score 26):

To access a nested attribute, you need to specify its name and then search through the object.

If you already know the exact path, then you can hardcode it in your script like so:

```
data['items'][1]['name']
```

these also work -

```
data.items[1].name
data['items'][1].name
data.items[1]['name']
```

When you don't know the exact name before hand, or a user is the one who provides the name for you. Then dynamically searching through the data structure is required. Some suggested here that the search can be done using a `for` loop, but there is a very simple way to traverse a path using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
const data = { code: 42, items: [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }] }
const path = [ 'items', '1', 'name']
let result = path.reduce((a,v) => a[v], data)
```

The path is a way to say: First take the object with key `items`, which happens to be an array. Then take the `1`-st element (0 index arrays). Last take the object with key `name` in that array element, which happens to be the string `bar`.

If you have a very long path, you might even use `String.split` to make all of this easier -

```
'items.1.name'.split('.').reduce((a,v) => a[v], data)
```

This is just plain JavaScript, without using any third party libraries like jQuery or lodash.

Answer (score 21):

### Here are 4 different methods mentioned to get the javascript object property:

```js
var data = {
  code: 42,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  }]
};

// Method 1
let method1 = data.items[1].name;
console.log(method1);

// Method 2
let method2 = data.items[1]["name"];
console.log(method2);

// Method 3
let method3 = data["items"][1]["name"];
console.log(method3);

// Method 4  Destructuring
let { items: [, { name: second_name }] } = data;
console.log(second_name);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything that isn't already in one of the other answers (like the accepted one)

Answer (score 20):

It's simple explanation:

```js
var data = {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
};

/*
1. `data` is object contain `items` object*/
console.log(data);

/*
2. `items` object contain array of two objects as elements*/
console.log(data.items);

/*
3. you need 2nd element of array - the `1` from `[0, 1]`*/
console.log(data.items[1]);

/*
4. and you need value of `name` property of 2nd object-element of array)*/
console.log(data.items[1].name);
```

Comment: Just would like to comment on this one real quick since the author of this question didn't pick a best answer. This would actually be the best answer. So anyone else is looking for an answer to this, this is best.

Answer (score 17):

You could use `lodash _get` function:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
```

Answer (score 15):

This question is quite old, so as a contemporary update. With the onset of ES2015 there are alternatives to get a hold of the data you require. There is now a feature called **object destructuring** for accessing nested objects.

```js
const data = {
  code: 42,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  }]
};

const {
  items: [, {
    name: secondName
  }]
} = data;

console.log(secondName);
```

The above example creates a variable called `secondName` from the `name` key from an array called `items`, the lonely `,` says skip the first object in the array.

Notably it's probably overkill for this example, as simple array acccess is easier to read, but it comes in useful when breaking apart objects in general.

This is very brief intro to your specific use case, destructuring can be an unusual syntax to get used to at first. I'd recommend reading [Mozilla's Destructuring Assignment documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to learn more.

Answer (score 14):

```
var ourStorage = {


"desk":    {
    "drawer": "stapler"
  },
"cabinet": {
    "top drawer": { 
      "folder1": "a file",
      "folder2": "secrets"
    },
    "bottom drawer": "soda"
  }
};
ourStorage.cabinet["top drawer"].folder2; // Outputs -> "secrets"
```

or

```
//parent.subParent.subsubParent["almost there"]["final property"]
```

Basically, use a dot between each descendant that unfolds underneath it and when you have object names made out of two strings, you must use the ["obj Name"] notation. Otherwise, just a dot would suffice;

Source:  https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/accessing-nested-objects

to add to this, accessing nested Arrays would happen like so:

```
var ourPets = [
  {
    animalType: "cat",
    names: [
      "Meowzer",
      "Fluffy",
      "Kit-Cat"
    ]
  },
  {
    animalType: "dog",
    names: [
      "Spot",
      "Bowser",
      "Frankie"
    ]
  }
];
ourPets[0].names[1]; // Outputs "Fluffy"
ourPets[1].names[0]; // Outputs "Spot"
```

Source: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/accessing-nested-arrays/

Another more useful document depicting the situation above: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#Bracket_notation

Property access via dot walking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation

Answer (score 13):

Accessing dynamically multi levels object.

```
var obj = {
  name: "john doe",
  subobj: {
    subsubobj: {
      names: "I am sub sub obj"
    }
  }
};

var level = "subobj.subsubobj.names";
level = level.split(".");

var currentObjState = obj;

for (var i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
  currentObjState = currentObjState[level[i]];
}

console.log(currentObjState);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andreitodorut/3mws3kjL/

Answer (score 13):

Just in case, anyone's visiting this question in 2017 or later and looking for an **easy-to-remember** way, here's an elaborate blog post on [Accessing Nested Objects in JavaScript](https://dev.to/flexdinesh/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript--9m4) without being bamboozled by

*Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined* error

### 1. Oliver Steele's nested object access pattern

The easiest and the cleanest way is to use Oliver Steele's nested object access pattern

```
const name = ((user || {}).personalInfo || {}).name;
```

With this notation, you'll never run into

*Cannot read property 'name' of undefined*.

You basically check if user exists, if not, you create an empty object on the fly. This way, the next level key will **always be accessed from an object that exists or an empty object**, but never from undefined.

### 2. Access Nested Objects Using Array Reduce

To be able to access nested arrays, you can write your own array reduce util.

```
const getNestedObject = (nestedObj, pathArr) => {
    return pathArr.reduce((obj, key) =>
        (obj && obj[key] !== 'undefined') ? obj[key] : undefined, nestedObj);
}

// pass in your object structure as array elements
const name = getNestedObject(user, ['personalInfo', 'name']);

// to access nested array, just pass in array index as an element the path array.
const city = getNestedObject(user, ['personalInfo', 'addresses', 0, 'city']);
// this will return the city from the first address item.
```

There is also an excellent type handling minimal library [typy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typy) that does all this for you.

Comment: This question is primarily about access properties that exist. There is already a question about what you are referring to (and already including most of your solutions): [Access Javascript nested objects safely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18178406/218196) or [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6491463/218196). But anyway: *"Unfortunately, you cannot access nested arrays with this trick."* Why not? Arrays are objects, so it should work just as well. Can you provide an example where it does not?

Comment: @FelixKling When we try to access arrays with Oliver Steele pattern, we won't be able to create array on 'n' length on the fly and access nth index without getting 'undefined' error. Ex. `((user || {}).address || new Array(3))[1].name`

Comment: You are not applying your pattern consistently. Of course `...[1].bar` would result in an error if the element `1` didn't exist. But that's also the case for `....foo.bar` if `foo` didn't exist. You have to "guard" accessing `1` as well, just like you "guard" any other property access. An array is just an object. An "array element" is just a property. Correctly applied it would be `(((user || {}).address || {})[1] || {}).name`.

Comment: This is great. It didn't strike me this way. Thank @FelixKling, I'll go update the blog posts.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan you should disclose that you're the author of typy, I just came here after reading your blog post

Answer (score 10):

Using **JSONPath** would be one of the most flexible solutions if you are willing to include a library:
https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath (node and browser)

For your use case the json path would be:

```
$..items[1].name
```

so:

```
var secondName = jsonPath.eval(data, "$..items[1].name");
```

Comment: Using eval() is not good solution. Instead first class function can be used.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer JQuery. It's cleaner and easy to read.

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function (key, value) {
  alert(value.<propertyname>);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for one or more objects that meets certain criteria you have a few options using [query-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-js)

```
//will return all elements with an id larger than 1
data.items.where(function(e){return e.id > 1;});
//will return the first element with an id larger than 1
data.items.first(function(e){return e.id > 1;});
//will return the first element with an id larger than 1 
//or the second argument if non are found
data.items.first(function(e){return e.id > 1;},{id:-1,name:""});
```

There's also a `single` and a `singleOrDefault` they work much like `first`and `firstOrDefault`respectively. The only difference is that they will throw if *more* than one match is found.

for further explanation of query-js you can start with this [post](http://runefs.com/2015/06/04/working-with-data-in-javascript/)

Comment: I would love to know how this could be improved. Care to leave a comment?

Answer (score 7):

### The Underscore js Way

Which is a JavaScript library that provides a whole mess of useful `functional programming` helpers without extending any built-in objects.

#### Solution:

```js
var data = {
  code: 42,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  }]
};

var item = _.findWhere(data.items, {
  id: 2
});
if (!_.isUndefined(item)) {
  console.log('NAME =>', item.name);
}

//using find - 

var item = _.find(data.items, function(item) {
  return item.id === 2;
});

if (!_.isUndefined(item)) {
  console.log('NAME =>', item.name);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Old question but as nobody mentioned lodash (just underscore).

In case you are already using lodash in your project, I think an elegant way to do this in a complex example:

**Opt 1**

```
_.get(response, ['output', 'fund', 'data', '0', 'children', '0', 'group', 'myValue'], '')
```

same as:

**Opt 2**

```
response.output.fund.data[0].children[0].group.myValue
```

The difference between the first and second option is that in the **Opt 1** if you have one of the properties missing (undefined) in the path you don't get an error, it returns you the third parameter.

For array filter lodash has `_.find()` but I'd rather use the regular `filter()`. But I still think the above method `_.get()` is super useful when working with really complex data. I faced in the past really complex APIs and it was handy!

I hope it can be useful for who's looking for options to manipulate really complex data which the title implies.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think questioner just only concern one level nested object, so I present the following demo to demonstrate how to access the node of deeply nested json object. All right, let's find the node with id '5'.

```js
var data = {
  code: 42,
  items: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'aaa',
    items: [{
        id: 3,
        name: 'ccc'
      }, {
        id: 4,
        name: 'ddd'
      }]
    }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bbb',
    items: [{
        id: 5,
        name: 'eee'
      }, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'fff'
      }]
    }]
};

var jsonloop = new JSONLoop(data, 'id', 'items');

jsonloop.findNodeById(data, 5, function(err, node) {
  if (err) {
    document.write(err);
  } else {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(node, null, 2));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dabeng/JSON-Loop/master/JSONLoop.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Dynamic approach

In below `deep(data,key)` function, you can use arbitrary `key` string - in your case `items[1].name` (you can use array notation `[i]` at any level) - if key is invalid then undefined is return.

```js
let deep = (o,k) => k.split('.').reduce((a,c,i) => {
    let m=c.match(/(.*?)\[(\d*)\]/);
    if(m && a!=null && a[m[1]]!=null) return a[m[1]][+m[2]];
    return a==null ? a: a[c];
},o);

// TEST

let key = 'items[1].name' // arbitrary deep-key

let data = {
    code: 42,
    items: [{ id: 11, name: 'foo'}, { id: 22, name: 'bar'},]
};

console.log( key,'=', deep(data,key) );
```

Answer (score 6):

In 2020, you can use @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining it is very easy to access nested values in an object.

```
 const obj = {
 foo: {
   bar: {
     baz: class {
   },
  },
 },
};

const baz = new obj?.foo?.bar?.baz(); // baz instance

const safe = new obj?.qux?.baz(); // undefined
const safe2 = new obj?.foo.bar.qux?.(); // undefined
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery's grep](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function lets you filter through an array:

```js
var data = {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
};

$.grep(data.items, function(item) {
    if (item.id === 2) {
        console.log(item.id); //console id of item
        console.log(item.name); //console name of item
        console.log(item); //console item object
        return item; //returns item object
    }

});
// Object {id: 2, name: "bar"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the syntax `jsonObject.key` to access the the value. And if you want access a value from an array, then you can use the syntax `jsonObjectArray[index].key`.

Here are the code examples to access various values to give you the idea.

```js
var data = {
    code: 42,
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'foo'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'bar'
    }]
};

// if you want 'bar'
console.log(data.items[1].name);

// if you want array of item names
console.log(data.items.map(x => x.name));

// get the id of the item where name = 'bar'
console.log(data.items.filter(x => (x.name == "bar") ? x.id : null)[0].id);
```

Answer (score 5):

this is how i have done this.

```
 let groups = [
        {
            id:1,
            title:"Group 1",
            members:[
                {
                    id:1,
                    name:"Aftab",
                    battry:'10%'
                },
                {
                    id:2,
                    name:"Jamal",
                },
                {
                    id:3,
                    name:"Hamid",
                },
                {
                    id:4,
                    name:"Aqeel",
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id:2,
            title:"Group 2",
            members:[
                {
                    id:1,
                    name:"Aftab",
                    battry:'10%'
                },
                {
                    id:2,
                    name:"Jamal",
                    battry:'10%'
                },
                {
                    id:3,
                    name:"Hamid",
                },
               
            ]
        },
        {
            id:3,
            title:"Group 3",
            members:[
                {
                    id:1,
                    name:"Aftab",
                    battry:'10%'
                },
                
                {
                    id:3,
                    name:"Hamid",
                },
                {
                    id:4,
                    name:"Aqeel",
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
    
    groups.map((item) => {
      //  if(item.id == 2){
        item.members.map((element) => {
             if(element.id == 1){
                 element.battry="20%"
             }
         })
        //}
    })
    
    groups.forEach((item) => {
        item.members.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(item)
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to find a path in a JSON string, you can dump your data into a tool to determine the path for you.

The Chrome developer console shows property paths when you hover over them in a nested JS object structure, which can be parsed from JSON using `JSON.parse(json)` if necessary:

[image: chrome console hovering an object key shows the path to get there on hover]

You can also copy the path to the clipboard:

[image: chrome console about to copy property path for object to clipboard using the context menu on a node]

Once you have a path on the clipboard, you will typically want to iterate arrays by replacing the offset indexers like `[0]` with a loop. You can then use the loop index `[i]` in its place, or use a `forEach` style function to replace the whole property and index.

Another tool is https://jsonpathfinder.com where you can click on the GUI elements. It'll generate the JS syntax for the path to the element like Chrome.

I wrote a simple tool you can run here, or at https://ggorlen.github.io/json-dive/. Paste your JSON string into the textarea, then click the node to copy its path to your clipboard. It has an option to generate Python/PHP style indexes with brackets rather than dots.

```js
/* code minified to make the tool easier to run without having to scroll */                                                         let bracketsOnly=!1,lastHighlighted={style:{}};const keyToStr=t=>!bracketsOnly&&/^[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z$_\d]*$/.test(t)?`.${toHTML(t)}`:`[&quot;${toHTML(t)}&quot;]`,pathToData=t=>`data-path="data${t.join("")}"`,htmlSpecialChars={"&":"&amp;","<":"&lt;",">":"&gt;",'"':"&quot;","'":"&#039;","\t":"\\t","\r":"\\r","\n":"\\n"," ":"&nbsp;"},toHTML=t=>(""+t).replace(/[&<>"'\t\r\n ]/g,t=>htmlSpecialChars[t]),makeArray=(t,e)=>`\n  [<ul ${pathToData(e)}>\n    ${t.map((t,a)=>{e.push(`[${a}]`);const n=`<li ${pathToData(e)}>\n        ${pathify(t,e).trim()},\n      </li>`;return e.pop(),n}).join("")}\n  </ul>]\n`,makeObj=(t,e)=>`\n  {<ul ${pathToData(e)}>\n    ${Object.entries(t).map(([t,a])=>{e.push(keyToStr(t));const n=`<li ${pathToData(e)}>\n        "${toHTML(t)}": ${pathify(a,e).trim()},\n      </li>`;return e.pop(),n}).join("")}\n  </ul>}\n`,pathify=(t,e=[])=>Array.isArray(t)?makeArray(t,e):"object"==typeof t&&t!=null?makeObj(t,e):toHTML("string"==typeof t?`"${t}"`:t),defaultJSON='{\n  "corge": "test JSON... \\n   asdf\\t asdf",\n  "foo-bar": [\n    {"id": 42},\n    [42, {"foo": {"baz": {"ba  r<>!\\t": true, "4quux": "garply"}}}]\n  ]\n}',$=document.querySelector.bind(document),$$=document.querySelectorAll.bind(document),resultEl=$("#result"),pathEl=$("#path"),tryToJSON=t=>{try{resultEl.innerHTML=pathify(JSON.parse(t)),$("#error").innerText=""}catch(t){resultEl.innerHTML="",$("#error").innerText=t}},copyToClipboard=t=>{const e=document.createElement("textarea");e.textContent=t,document.body.appendChild(e),e.select(),document.execCommand("copy"),document.body.removeChild(e)},flashAlert=(t,e=2e3)=>{const a=document.createElement("div");a.textContent=t,a.classList.add("alert"),document.body.appendChild(a),setTimeout(()=>a.remove(),e)},handleClick=t=>{t.stopPropagation(),copyToClipboard(t.target.dataset.path),flashAlert("copied!"),$("#path-out").textContent=t.target.dataset.path},handleMouseOut=t=>{lastHighlighted.style.background="transparent",pathEl.style.display="none"},handleMouseOver=t=>{pathEl.textContent=t.target.dataset.path,pathEl.style.left=`${t.pageX+30}px`,pathEl.style.top=`${t.pageY}px`,pathEl.style.display="block",lastHighlighted.style.background="transparent",(lastHighlighted=t.target.closest("li")).style.background="#0ff"},handleNewJSON=t=>{tryToJSON(t.target.value),[...$$("#result *")].forEach(t=>{t.addEventListener("click",handleClick),t.addEventListener("mouseout",handleMouseOut),t.addEventListener("mouseover",handleMouseOver)})};$("textarea").addEventListener("change",handleNewJSON),$("textarea").addEventListener("keyup",handleNewJSON),$("textarea").value=defaultJSON,$("#brackets").addEventListener("change",t=>{bracketsOnly=!bracketsOnly,handleNewJSON({target:{value:$("textarea").value}})}),handleNewJSON({target:{value:defaultJSON}});
```

```css
/**/                                                                                       *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:monospace;margin:0;padding:0}html{height:100%}#path-out{background-color:#0f0;padding:.3em}body{margin:0;height:100%;position:relative;background:#f8f8f8}textarea{width:100%;height:110px;resize:vertical}#opts{background:#e8e8e8;padding:.3em}#opts label{padding:.3em}#path{background:#000;transition:all 50ms;color:#fff;padding:.2em;position:absolute;display:none}#error{margin:.5em;color:red}#result ul{list-style:none}#result li{cursor:pointer;border-left:1em solid transparent}#result li:hover{border-color:#ff0}.alert{background:#f0f;padding:.2em;position:fixed;bottom:10px;right:10px}
```

```html
<!-- -->                                                                                                    <div class="wrapper"><textarea></textarea><div id="opts"><label>brackets only: <input id="brackets"type="checkbox"></label></div><div id="path-out">click a node to copy path to clipboard</div><div id="path"></div><div id="result"></div><div id="error"></div></div>
```

Unminified (also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ggorlen/json-dive)):

```js
let bracketsOnly = false;
let lastHighlighted = {style: {}};

const keyToStr = k =>
  !bracketsOnly && /^[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z$_\d]*$/.test(k) 
    ? `.${toHTML(k)}`
    : `[&quot;${toHTML(k)}&quot;]`
;
const pathToData = p => `data-path="data${p.join("")}"`;

const htmlSpecialChars = {
  "&": "&amp;",
  "<": "&lt;",
  ">": "&gt;",
  '"': "&quot;",
  "'": "&#039;",
  "\t": "\\t",
  "\r": "\\r",
  "\n": "\\n",
  " ": "&nbsp;",
};
const toHTML = x => ("" + x)
  .replace(/[&<>"'\t\r\n ]/g, m => htmlSpecialChars[m])
;

const makeArray = (x, path) => `
  [<ul ${pathToData(path)}>
    ${x.map((e, i) => {
      path.push(`[${i}]`);
      const html = `<li ${pathToData(path)}>
        ${pathify(e, path).trim()},
      </li>`;
      path.pop();
      return html;
    }).join("")}
  </ul>]
`;
const makeObj = (x, path) => `
  {<ul ${pathToData(path)}>
    ${Object.entries(x).map(([k, v]) => {
      path.push(keyToStr(k));
      const html = `<li ${pathToData(path)}>
        "${toHTML(k)}": ${pathify(v, path).trim()},
      </li>`;
      path.pop();
      return html;
    }).join("")}
  </ul>}
`;

const pathify = (x, path=[]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(x)) {
    return makeArray(x, path);
  }
  else if (typeof x === "object" && x !== null) {
    return makeObj(x, path);
  }
  
  return toHTML(typeof x === "string" ? `"${x}"` : x);
};

const defaultJSON = `{
  "corge": "test JSON... \\n   asdf\\t asdf",
  "foo-bar": [
    {"id": 42},
    [42, {"foo": {"baz": {"ba  r<>!\\t": true, "4quux": "garply"}}}]
  ]
}`;

const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
const resultEl = $("#result");
const pathEl = $("#path");

const tryToJSON = v => {
  try {
    resultEl.innerHTML = pathify(JSON.parse(v));
    $("#error").innerText = "";
  }
  catch (err) {
    resultEl.innerHTML = "";
    $("#error").innerText = err;
  }
};

const copyToClipboard = text => {
  const ta = document.createElement("textarea");
  ta.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(ta);
  ta.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(ta);
};

const flashAlert = (text, timeoutMS=2000) => {
  const alert = document.createElement("div");
  alert.textContent = text;
  alert.classList.add("alert");
  document.body.appendChild(alert);
  setTimeout(() => alert.remove(), timeoutMS);
};

const handleClick = e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  copyToClipboard(e.target.dataset.path);
  flashAlert("copied!");
  $("#path-out").textContent = e.target.dataset.path;
};

const handleMouseOut = e => {
  lastHighlighted.style.background = "transparent";
  pathEl.style.display = "none";
};

const handleMouseOver = e => {
  pathEl.textContent = e.target.dataset.path;
  pathEl.style.left = `${e.pageX + 30}px`;
  pathEl.style.top = `${e.pageY}px`;
  pathEl.style.display = "block";
  lastHighlighted.style.background = "transparent";
  lastHighlighted = e.target.closest("li");
  lastHighlighted.style.background = "#0ff";
};

const handleNewJSON = e => {
  tryToJSON(e.target.value);
  [...$$("#result *")].forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    e.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut);
    e.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver);
  });
};
$("textarea").addEventListener("change", handleNewJSON);
$("textarea").addEventListener("keyup", handleNewJSON);
$("textarea").value = defaultJSON;
$("#brackets").addEventListener("change", e => {
  bracketsOnly = !bracketsOnly;
  handleNewJSON({target: {value: $("textarea").value}});
});
handleNewJSON({target: {value: defaultJSON}});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

#path-out {
  background-color: #0f0;
  padding: 0.3em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  resize: vertical;
}

#opts {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
#opts label {
  padding: 0.3em;
}

#path {
  background: black;
  transition: all 0.05s;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

#error {
  margin: 0.5em;
  color: red;
}

#result ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#result li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1em solid transparent;
}
#result li:hover {
  border-color: #ff0;
}

.alert {
  background: #f0f;
  padding: 0.2em;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div id="opts">
    <label>
      brackets only: <input id="brackets" type="checkbox">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div id="path-out">click a node to copy path to clipboard</div>
  <div id="path"></div>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div id="error"></div>
</div>
```

This isn't intended as a substitute for [learning how to fish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11922384/6243352) but can save time once you do know.

Answer (score 3):

```
// const path = 'info.value[0].item'
// const obj = { info: { value: [ { item: 'it works!' } ], randominfo: 3 }  }
// getValue(path, obj)

export const getValue = ( path , obj) => {
  const newPath = path.replace(/\]/g, "")
  const arrayPath = newPath.split(/[\[\.]+/) || newPath;

  const final = arrayPath.reduce( (obj, k) => obj ?  obj[k] : obj, obj)
  return final;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer using [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan).

When accessing a single entry, this answer doesn't really provide much benefit over vanilla javascript. However interacting with multiple fields at the same time this answer can be more performant.

Here is how you could interact with a single field

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { code: 42, items: [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }] };

const get = (haystack, needle) => objectScan([needle], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'value'
})(haystack);

const set = (haystack, needle, value) => objectScan([needle], {
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ parent, property }) => {
    parent[property] = value;
    return true;
  }
})(haystack);

console.log(get(data, 'items[1].name'));
// => bar

console.log(set(data, 'items[1].name', 'foo2'));
// => true
console.log(data);
// => { code: 42, items: [ { id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'foo2' } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

and here is how you could interact with multiple fields at the same time

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { code: 42, items: [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }] };

const get = (haystack, ...needles) => objectScan(needles, {
  joined: true,
  rtn: 'entry'
})(haystack);

const set = (haystack, actions) => objectScan(Object.keys(actions), {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ matchedBy, parent, property }) => {
    matchedBy.forEach((m) => {
      parent[property] = actions[m];
    })
    return true;
  }
})(haystack);

console.log(get(data, 'items[0].name', 'items[1].name'));
// => [ [ 'items[1].name', 'bar' ], [ 'items[0].name', 'foo' ] ]

console.log(set(data, {
  'items[0].name': 'foo1',
  'items[1].name': 'foo2'
}));
// => 2
console.log(data);
// => { code: 42, items: [ { id: 1, name: 'foo1' }, { id: 2, name: 'foo2' } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

---

And here is how one could find an entity in a deeply nested object searching by id (as asked in comment)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = { code: 42, items: [{ id: 1, name: 'aaa', items: [{ id: 3, name: 'ccc' }, { id: 4, name: 'ddd' }] }, { id: 2, name: 'bbb', items: [{ id: 5, name: 'eee' }, { id: 6, name: 'fff' }] }] };

const findItemById = (haystack, id) => objectScan(['**(^items$).id'], {
  abort: true,
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'parent',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value === id
})(haystack);

console.log(findItemById(myData, 5));
// => { id: 5, name: 'eee' }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: I am about pretty certain that is node.js, he wants to know how to do it in javascript. If he did want to use node.js, he would of put it in his tags. But that would help me though as I am trying to look for an answer to do this in node.js.

Comment: Nodejs is javascript. But if I understand your comment correctly: I thought you can use any npm packages in "browser javascript" using eg babel?

Comment: node.js is server side, javascript is client side. And no, you can't use npm packages in "browser javascript", just me, I have tried. I tried mainly for the heck of it. But even if it was node.js, you are basically saying a long and complex way. @timnavigate answer actually would solve the problem.

Comment: You definitely can https://stackoverflow.com/q/49562978/1030413 - The package I liked can do a lot. So based on your use case it might be nice to have that available. I understand that there might be work in setting it up

Comment: @JonathanJ.Pecany I've edited the example to make it runnable and showcase how you could use it in the browser.

Comment: I believe this is answering a different question than was asked.  The question is not about searching an object, it seems, but only about how to access the properties.  Thus `object.items[1].name` would be the beginning of an answer, possibly followed by a discussion on null-handling.

Comment: Been a while that I answered this. Let me take a look!

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thank you for pointing this out. I've completely reworked the answer

Comment: It's an old question; I just ran across it as a suggested duplicate.  This answer was near the top.  But I still think you're still trying to do something much more than was asked.  If I'm not mistaken (and perhaps I am)  [Rahu Vala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791155/1243641) is the sort of help needed.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yeah, really depends on what people are looking that come here. I think that answer is also beyond scope of the questions. Anyways, I've updated my answer to showcase a solution for that problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is really simple and it can be achieved trough recursivity:

```
const json_object = {
        "item1":{
            "name": "apple",
            "value": 2,
        },
        "item2":{
            "name": "pear",
            "value": 4,
        },
        "item3":{
            "name": "mango",
            "value": 3,
            "prices": {
                "1": "9$",
                "2": "59$",
                "3": "1$"
            }
        }
    }
    
    function walkJson(json_object){
        for(obj in json_object){
            if(typeof json_object[obj] === 'string'){
                console.log(`${obj}=>${json_object[obj]}`);
            }else{
                console.log(`${obj}=>${json_object[obj]}`);
                walkJson(json_object[obj]);
            }
        }           
    }
    
    walkJson(json_object);
```

Comment: @jetyzi maybe this answer your duplicated question my friend

Comment: Another useful tiny JS library to manipulate and access  objects in a familiar way, very useful.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/selectql.js

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic, recursive and functional approach to unravel arbitrary JSON trees:

```
handlers = {
    list:  iterate,
    dict:  delve,
    str:   emit_li,
    float: emit_li,
}

def emit_li(stuff, strong=False):
    emission = '<li><strong>%s</strong></li>' if strong else '<li>%s</li>'
    print(emission % stuff)

def iterate(a_list):
    print('<ul>')
    map(unravel, a_list)
    print('</ul>')

def delve(a_dict):
    print('<ul>')
    for key, value in a_dict.items():
        emit_li(key, strong=True)
        unravel(value)
    print('</ul>')

def unravel(structure):
    h = handlers[type(structure)]
    return h(structure)

unravel(data)
```

where *data* is a python list (parsed from a JSON text string):

```
data = [
    {'data': {'customKey1': 'customValue1',
           'customKey2': {'customSubKey1': {'customSubSubKey1': 'keyvalue'}}},
  'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 37.3860517, 'lng': -122.0838511},
               'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 37.4508789,
                                          'lng': -122.0446721},
                            'southwest': {'lat': 37.3567599,
                                          'lng': -122.1178619}}},
  'name': 'Mountain View',
  'scope': 'GOOGLE',
  'types': ['locality', 'political']}
]
```

Comment: This question is about JavaScript, not Python. Not sure whether there is an equivalent question for Python.

Comment: Please see [Python Accessing Nested JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306653/python-accessing-nested-json-data?noredirect=1&lq=1) for Python.

Answer (score 0):

## Access Nested Objects & Arrays in Python Like JavaScript

- below `OLD_JSObject` Class snippet from https://pypi.org/project/jsobject/
- this package no longer work after 3.4
- but this package need some additional modification thats works for me
- `Object` Function that allows to access nested object value & print objects too

```
class OLD_JSObject(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, k):
        try:
            return self[k]
        except:
            return self.__getitem__(k)

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        if type(v) == dict:
            self[k] = self.__class__(v)
        else:
            self[k] = v

    def merge(self, mapping):
        for key in mapping:
            if key not in self:
                self[key] = mapping[key]
                continue

            if isinstance(self[key], dict) and isinstance(mapping[key], dict):
                self[key].merge(mapping[key])
            elif isinstance(self[key], list) and isinstance(mapping[key], list):
                self[key].extend(mapping[key])
            elif self[key] == mapping[key]:
                pass
            else:
                self[key] = mapping[key]
                # raise Exception('Conflict')


def Object(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        attrs = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            attrs[key] = Object(value)
        return OLD_JSObject(attrs)
    else:
        return data
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using Bracket Notation:**

```
var secondItemName = data.items[1].name;
```

**Using Destructuring Assignment:**

```
var { items: [, secondItem] } = data;
var secondItemName = secondItem.name;
```

**Using Array's find() method:**

```
var secondItem = data.items.find(item => item.id === 2);
var secondItemName = secondItem.name;
```

Answer (score -4):

My `stringdata` is coming from PHP file but still, I indicate here in `var`. When i directly take my json into `obj` it will nothing show thats why i put my json file as

`var obj=JSON.parse(stringdata);` 
so after that i get `message` obj and show in alert box then I get `data` which is json array and store in one varible `ArrObj` then i read first object of that array with key value like this `ArrObj[0].id`

```
     var stringdata={
        "success": true,
        "message": "working",
        "data": [{
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "foo"
         }]
      };

                var obj=JSON.parse(stringdata);
                var key = "message";
                alert(obj[key]);
                var keyobj = "data";
                var ArrObj =obj[keyobj];

                alert(ArrObj[0].id);
```

Comment: The example is confusing because `stringjson` is not a string.

Answer (score -5):

**Using lodash would be good solution**

Ex:

```
var object = { 'a': { 'b': { 'c': 3 } } };                                                                                               
_.get(object, 'a.b.c');                                                                                             
// => 3
```

Comment: How is this different from [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](//stackoverflow.com/a/44874294)?

Comment: ^^ This answer allows you to access via dynamic keys easier