# JSON response from URL

Tags: html, ajax, json

Hey I'm trying to retrieve data from a json file I have hosted on my server but it's not working, I'm not sure what is wrong as I'm not the most well versed in this topic. Any tips are appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button").click(function () {
    $.getJSON({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some URL will go here",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#div1").append(result);
        }
    });
});
});
```

heres the fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ahuston12/E5SzH/

Comment: Have you checked that the JSON file is accessible from the outside (e.g., can you open it in a browser)?

Comment: Did u checked what type of response/ error you are getting.

Comment: open the js console (eg. ctrl+shift+j in chrome) and check whether the json resource is loaded.

Comment: for getting JSOn values use  "result.d"

Comment: the JSON is definitely accessible, I also tried other json files that I know are working and I get the same problem

Comment: What message appears in the networking tab of the chrome dev tools?

Comment: gives me back [object Object], Method: Option, Status: Pending

Comment: i think you have mixed up function signatures. see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for details - your call should actually be `$.ajax(...`instead of `$.getJSON(...` or you need to change the arguments to `$.getJSON(<url>, <success callback>)`. btw, do you really use the `POST` method (if you query the webservice with a tailored url, you don't) ?.

Comment: @AllanHuston: does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/Hr5LE/) work woth your url to the json service ?

Comment: You could be right, like I said I'm just trying to get this work with little experience. Is there anything else in the function that's incorrect if I use the $.ajax signature

Comment: @AllanHuston: you most certainly need to preprocess `result`into somenthing that you can actually insert into the dom. `result`will contain an object (ie. a nested object structure which the json notation represents). have a look at [this fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/Hr5LE/)](http://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/Hr5LE/), it's a working example using a public json web service as data source.

Comment: I'll definitely have to try this method thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open a modern browser like Firefox or chrome and open the developer tools. Navigate to the page that contains the above code and monitor the "network" tab to see the related http request triggered via ajax. You can then see the request + response including header, body and return codes. This should help to figure out the problem.

Comment: It looks like it's not loading properly but I'm not sure why. It doesn't even go to my link it goes to my desktop apparently? gives me back [object Object], Method: Option, Status: Pending

Comment: Maybe you can post the link you are trying? What is the HTTP response code?

Answer (score 0):

You should show us what's going on the server side.
It doesn't seems to be problems on this jquery code so i guess it's from server.

You can check the response value to see the problem :
   on chrome ctrl+j -> network. You'll see your request, click on it to see details like the server's response.

Comment: I checked using firebug and chrome and I'm not seeing any net activity oddly enough

Comment: So it seems that your ajax is never called.

Comment: correct, I'm not sure why maybe it has something to do with my function?

Comment: try to put onclick to test. Sily question but do you include jquery on your page ? ^^

Comment: yeah I'm just using to google library and I do see that request going out when the page loads but nothing when the button is clicked.

Comment: You're now aware that the problem doesn't come from your json file. Get dat button to be clicked bro !

Comment: changed it to just display an alert and that works, I'm at a total loss haha

Comment: maybe try with $.ajax with dataType:'json'

Answer (score 0):

If you have FireBug installed in your Mozilla Firefox open it, in that you can see Net Tab . If you click that you can able to see what kind of response you are getting. I ahve attached the Image For your reference.  And for getting a JSON result use "result.d".

[image: Ajax Response Image]

Comment: When I click my button I'm not getting any net activity? Which might explain why chrome showed it was trying to load a file from my desktop?

Comment: @AllanHuston Use mozilla Firefox

Comment: I used firefox for firebug but didn't get anything for the response, It didn't like there was any net activity at all except for my ajax request for jquery

Comment: You are using $("#button") in Jquery are you using "button" as the id name for button

Comment: yeah I was hoping it was something stupid like that but it was one of the first things I checked hah

Comment: @AllanHuston First check whether the button event is getting fired or not

Comment: It looks like it is, not sure how to check to make sure though

Comment: Try this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105449/getjson-to-fetch-data-from-this-json-array

Answer (score 0):

The url that you are using doesn't return a json response, it returns a javascript file that charge a json result into a variable, because of that you can't get the result.. if you try with other site that returns information in json format like [this](http://headers.jsontest.com/) you are going to get the data:

```
$.getJSON("http://headers.jsontest.com/", function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    );
```